# Can the main (or entry-point) function be implemented as a lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, program-entry-point

Is this valid under the recently updated standard?

```
auto main = [](int argc, char* argv[]) -> int
{
    return 0;
};
```

My best guess is that it depends on whether main() MUST be a function, or if it is allowed to be any globally scoped symbol that is callable (with `()`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, and here's why:

> `[n3290: 3.6.1/1]:` **A program shall contain a global function called
>   main**, which is the designated start of the program. It is
>   implementation-defined whether a program in a freestanding environment
>   is required to define a main function. [ *Note:* In a freestanding
>   environment, start-up and termination is implementation-defined;
>   startup contains the execution of constructors for objects of
>   namespace scope with static storage duration; termination contains the
>   execution of destructors for objects with static storage duration.
>   *—end note* ]

Lambdas are not functions, but function objects or functors:

> `[n3290: 5.1.2/3]:` **The type of the *lambda-expression*** (which is
>   also the type of the closure object) **is a** unique, unnamed nonunion
>   **class type** — called the *closure type* — whose properties are described below. [..]

Comment: Interestingly enough, Visual C++ 2010 will have a linking error when you try to do this, BUT, if you redefine the entry point to a captured lambda object, it compiles and links fine, which then crashes with an access violation when it tries to execute the entry point.

Comment: @MichaelPrice: I'm not sure whether a diagnostic would be required here. I can't remember the rule specifically.

Answer (score 14):

No, `main` is required to be a global function and cannot be a function object or anything else. See ISO/IEC 14882:2011 § 3.6.1 Main Function.

> A program shall contain a global function called main, which is the designated start of the program.

And from paragraph 2

> All implementations shall allow both of the following definitions of
>   main:
>
> `int main() { /* ... */ }`
>
> and
>
> `int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }`

There is no requirement for implementations to allow any other definitions.

Comment: A quote from the standard would make the answer even better :) Especially as you know the exact section.

Comment: Any chance for a quote of the standard?

Comment: Correct. However technically in the assembler code generated does not guarantee main to even be a function, hence recursively calling main has undefined behaviour :-)

Comment: Allowing both of those definitions says nothing about alternative ones.

Comment: Yeah, so an implementation _could_ support it, but it seems like it's not required by this section.

Answer (score 1):

main() must be a function because of the way it's called from within with the system libraries .  It is part of the POSIX.1 standard and governs the way C linkage works

The main linkage has to be an extern global, it cannot be inlined or made static because it's called from within the libc and typically from a function called _start.

As an example,  typical implementation of _start in glibc is:

```
int _start() {
     __libc_init(argc, argv, __environ);
     exit(main(argc, argv, __environ));
}
```

Various libc implementations will do it in a similar fashion.

In C++ the main function must be declared in the global scope (i.e.) ::main(); again because it is called from an init-like function such as _start for libc on *nix function above after execution...

Comment: C is a red herring. C++ compilers ignore this anyway, as they need to insert extra code to call ctors for globals before main is called. And obviously, they need to initialize the C++ library too, not just libc.